# Break two Dates financial year wise in Oracle

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I want query or steps to break difference between two dates financial year wise.

For Example :- Table has one row with following data

```
NAME         From_Date       To_Date  
ABC         01-MAR-2020     30-APR-2022

I want output as breakup of dates financial year wise that is 

NAME   From_Date    To_Date
ABC    01-MAR-2020  31-MAR-2020
ABC    01-APR-2020  31-MAR-2021
ABC    01-APR-2021  31-MAR-2022
ABC    01-APR-2022  30-APR-2022
```

Any input will help me a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a recursive sub-query factoring clause:

```sql
WITH financial_years ( name, from_date, to_date, end_date ) AS (
  SELECT name,
         from_date,
         LEAST(
           ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( ADD_MONTHS( from_date, -3 ), 'YY' ), 15 )
             - INTERVAL '1' DAY,
           to_date
         ),
         to_date
  FROM   table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT name,
         to_date + INTERVAL '1' DAY,
         LEAST( ADD_MONTHS( to_date, 12 ), end_date ),
         end_date
  FROM   financial_years
  WHERE  to_date < end_date
)
SELECT name,
       from_date,
       to_date
FROM   financial_years;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( NAME, From_Date, To_Date ) AS
SELECT 'ABC', DATE '2020-03-01', DATE '2022-04-30' FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

> ```
> NAME | FROM_DATE | TO_DATE  
> :--- | :-------- | :--------
> ABC  | 01-MAR-20 | 31-MAR-20
> ABC  | 01-APR-20 | 31-MAR-21
> ABC  | 01-APR-21 | 31-MAR-22
> ABC  | 01-APR-22 | 30-APR-22
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4637e5c5097cb191e996a93e2e168e5e)*